# List Item, customer NopCommerce

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

How can I get the list of Items in Cart, with very simple code? (i need it in a controller, plugin)
It should be in version 4.20 Nopcommerce

and also get customer info , if the costumer is logged in?
And if the customer not logged in, create a new account when place order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ShoppingCartService to get the items of a user's cart:

```
var cart = _shoppingCartService.GetShoppingCart(_workContext.CurrentCustomer, ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart, _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);
```

Please consider that you have to inject these interfaces to your controller: `IShoppingCartService, IWorkContext, IStoreContext`

Comment: Hi, i had test and it works, i get all item in for each loop

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestStandardController : BasePluginController
        {
          #region Fields
        private readonly IShoppingCartService _shoppingCartService;
        private readonly IWorkContext _workContext;
        private readonly IStoreContext _storeContext;
        #endregion

        #region Ctor
        public TestStandardController(
        IShoppingCartService shoppingCartService,
        IWorkContext workContext,
        IStoreContext storeContext
     )
    {
        _shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
        _workContext = workContext;
        _storeContext = storeContext;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods


    public IActionResult Index()

       var cart = 
_shoppingCartService.GetShoppingCart(_workContext.CurrentCustomer, 
ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart, _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);

        return View("~/Plugins/Payments.test/Views/getps.cshtml");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `IWorkContext` interface has the property named `CurrentCustomer`.`WebWorkContext` class implements the interface and sets the customer's information. The `CurrentCustomer` property contains information about the customer and his/her shopping cart items.

To use this property you need to inject the `IWorkContext` interface in your constructor since NopCommerce uses constructor based dependency injection.

```
public class PluginController: BasePluginController
{
   private readonly IWorkContext _workContext;
    public PluginController(IWorkContext workContext)
    {
    _workContext=workContext;
    }
   
    private IActionResult GetCustomerAndShoppingCartItems()
    {
     var currentCustomer= _workContext.CurrentCustomer;
     var shoppingCartItems= currentCustomer.ShoppingCartItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this ,  i will also update costumer address, when costumer chose invoice we will only delivery to couturier living address. Are there some simple why to change address when place order?